# Access violation when passing BSTR string to _bstr_t or CComBSTR constructor

Tags: c++, com, crash, access-violation, bstr

I have BSTR string which is passed from COM server. When I put this string into _bstr_t (or CComBSTR) constructor then access violation is occurred. I checked this exception and found that this exception raised only when BSTR is empty (or null).

I was trying to put nulled BSTR explicitly to _bstr_t constructor and this works fine:

```
BSTR bstr = NULL;
_bstr_t t(bstr, false); 

cout << t.length() << endl;
```

But with BSTR which is passed from COM server this don't work - access violation exception is ocurred when string is empty or null (or maybe corrupted?)

I found that this workaround works fine:

```
if (SysStringLen(bstrFromCOMserver) > 0) {
    _bstr_t t(bstrFromCOMserver, false);    
    cout << t.length() << endl;
}
```

But I want to know why this don't work directly with _bstr_t or CComBSTR wrappers:

```
_bstr_t t(bstrFromCOMserver, false);
if (t.length() > 0) {...}
```

**Update:**

How COM server pass BSTR string:

```
void CALLBACK CProxy_ISTIQuoteEvents::OnSTIQuoteSnap(const structSTIQuoteSnap& structQuoteSnap) const { 
        if (SysStringLen(structQuoteSnap.bstrUpdateTime) > 0) {
            _bstr_t updateTime(structQuoteSnap.bstrUpdateTime, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show how you call the COM server? E.g: `CComBSTR str; server->GetString(&str);`

Comment: I added peace of code. BSTR string is field of struct which is passed by reference to event handler.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. Is `OnSTIQuoteSnap` a method of your COM server? If so, how do you actually return the string? Anyway, this code looks wrong. Your `_bstr_t updateTime(structQuoteSnap.bstrUpdateTime, false)` is just an automatic stack variable. Because you specify `false` in its constructor, it takes over the passed BSTR string and frees its as soon as it goes out of its {} scope. Maybe this is the problem.

Comment: COM server fire events and I use event sink clas, derived from IDispEventSimpleImpl.

No, _bstr_t object is used in it's scope and then he become unnecessary. BUT I tried set second parameter to true in _bstr_t constructor and now it seems worked! Why? MSDN writes that if we set fCopy to true in the constructor then _bstr_t makes a copy of passed BSTR string using SysAllocString. But as I understand I don't need a copy of BSTR because passed BSTR string is already in the structure.

Comment: If `OnSTIQuoteSnap` is a method of your event sink, you should make a copy of this string. The caller (the server) keeps the ownership over `structQuoteSnap` structure and all its fields. By not making a copy of `bstrUpdateTime`, you 'steal' the ownership over the memory allocated for the string, and free this memory as soon as your local `_bstr_t` smart pointer variable goes out of scope. The server knows  nothing about that and may continue using `bstrUpdateTime` and eventually try to free the same memory twice.

Comment: Yes, OnSTIQuoteSnap is a method of my event sink. Thank You so much for your explanation! :)

Comment: No problem, hope that solved the problem. I posted it as the answer, so the question doesn't show up unanswered in the search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OnSTIQuoteSnap` methods belongs to an event sink and is called back by the server, as we clarified in the comments. Thus, the server (as the caller) keeps the ownership over `structQuoteSnap` structure and all of its fields. `updateTime` is a local smart-pointer variable that should be making a copy of the string (`structQuoteSnap.bstrUpdateTime`), but it doesn't (as `false` is passed to its constructor), so it rather takes over the BSTR's memory. This memory is freed as soon as `updateTime` goes out of scope. The server knows nothing about that and may continue using `bstrUpdateTime` and may eventually try to free the same memory twice.